# Can we use same serializer for POST, PUT & GET?

Tags: django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

Can we use same serializer for creating, updating and getting a resource. is it a best practice to do so ?

Comment: `Post`, `Put`, and `Get` all relate to things that a view set does, and you only ever need to specify one serializer on a `ModelViewSet`. So what happened when you tried?

Answer (score 0):

> Can we use same serializer for creating, updating and getting a resource.

Why, yes, of course. Even more than that, we can use the exact same serializer for partially updating (PATCH) and deleting (DELETE) a resource.

This is because the serializer doesn't actually "knows" about all of these operations, it only serializes and deserializes data -- it is the view that handles http methods.

> is it a best practice to do so ?

It is most definitely not bad practice.

But is it good ? It really depends on what type of behaviour you are expecting for each of these, whether you have nested objects or not, etc.

I would strongly suggest you read more from the docs, especially about [ModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer).

Good luck.